# How to disable/enable sound effects in my application?

Tags: android, button, audio, android-mediaplayer

In my application all my buttons have their own sound effects. I just want two button in my setting to disable/enable sound effects in whole application.

I enable sound effects for each button like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.laser);
mp.start();
```

but how I can's disable, and also I try this code:

```
setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

but the point is that I just want to disable/enable sound effects by user's selection.

I was wondering if anyone could suggest me any solution.

Comment: Use a SharedPreferences to give the user the ability to switch the sound effects on and off. It's just a boolean to be read at the startup.

Comment: Is there any samlpe to suggest me, plz

Comment: Look in StackOverflow. Or google `android sharedpreferences`